# Want to be transferred, but no one has said a word about it, what to do? Health Declining

Tags: management, internal-transfer

I recently asked one of my corporate managers for my department, who runs all of the departments for a transfer. The reasons for the transfer is due to a toxic work environment, with numerous issues that are affecting my health in many ways. The corporate manager for my department agreed, and said he'd like to put me in a new location where someone with my skillset is badly needed.

This was one week ago. He said he told my District Manager, and he was basically on board. Nothing yet has happened since. My general store manager hasn't said a word, nor have I gotten any correspondence from my DM about the transfer, or even asking me why.

The corporate manager may have reasons to say he asked, but really did not, or may have answers, but is not telling me what is going on. However, when I ask him, he tells me he hasn't heard anything.

My question is 2 fold, do I go above the corporate department manager's head and ask my DM straight out what my transfer status is? & If yes, should I state a toxic work environment as the reason, or should I just be general about it?

For some background, the department manager is a pretty good friend, but he may be keeping info from me. The DM is really great as far as I know. My GM has always liked my work, but I have taken many sick days as of late due to the environment and it's affects on my health.

This whole transfer mess is... well... a mess. 
Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: (If in the USA) - If your mental health is declining to a point where you're unwell, see a doctor and get a diagnosis to use for FMLA.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A week is a rather short period of time. Companies usually don't move that fast. 
Give them a fair chance to work out a new position for you before you panic.

Comment: That presumed you're a good fit for the position that opened up, or that they can shuffle things to make a suitable position. It's not always that simple; you aren't the only person in the equation. Give it a while longer, then you can consider checking in "to see if there's anything I can do to help this happen",  and incidentally you can ask what the likely timeframe would be .